# Cache or pre render leaflet map in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

I am trying to map ~8000 polygons using leaflet and run into performance issues.
As I am using the map within a shiny app, I was wondering if its possible to somehow cache or pre-render the map.

Note that in my case, I have different layers of polygons that are swapped following [this approach](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/496#issuecomment-650122985).

A small MWE would be this:

The data can be downloaded from [here](https://www.suche-postleitzahl.org/downloads)

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(sf)

## Download Shapefile
file <- "plz-gebiete.shp"

if (!file.exists(file)) {
  url <- "https://www.suche-postleitzahl.org/download_files/public/plz-gebiete.shp.zip"
  zipfile <- paste0(file, ".zip")
  download.file(url, zipfile)
  unzip(zipfile)
}

df <- st_read(file, options = "ENCODING=UTF-8")

# If possible: pre-render the map here!

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap", width = "700px", height = "700px")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      addPolygons(data = df, weight = 1, color = "black")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It takes around 16 seconds on my machine to render the map with the polygons.

If possible, I would like to pre-render the map once, save it as an `.rds` file, and load it on demand. Note that I know the width/height of the map within the app (here set to 700px). But something like

```
map <- renderLeaflet({leaflet() %>% ...})
saveRDS(map, "renderedmap.rds")

map <- readRDS("renderedmap.rds")

# within server()
output$mymap <- map
```

does not result in any performance gains.

Alternatively, I have tried to load the leaflet asynchronously so that other parts of the app can be rendered/interacted with but to no avail.

Any ideas how to solve or circumnavigate this problem?

Comment: You can change the precision. A reduction to 0.001 reduces the file to 34MB and a reduction to 0.01 and saving as json weighs about 6MB.
So it's up to you whether you need very accurate maps.

Comment: You could try out [leafgl](https://github.com/r-spatial/leafgl) or `leafem::addFgb` which uses the performant Flatgeobuf format.

Comment: I have looked into leafgl, but found no working solution for recoloring the polygons. `addFgb` looks like a good solution. Do you mind posting a complete example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 2 following approaches dont exactly answer your question, but they are definitly more performant alternatives compared to `leaflet::addPolygons`.

**Using Flatgeobuf Format:**

Based on the description from `leafem::addFgb`:

> Flatgeobuf can stream the data chunk by chunk so that rendering of the
> map is more or less instantaneous. The map is responsive while data is
> still loading so that popup queries, zooming and panning will work
> even though not all data has been rendered yet.

I think the dataset are linestrings, that is why `fillColor` seems to be ignored.

```
library(leaflet)
library(leafem)
library(shiny)

# via URL (data around 13mb)
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bjornharrtell/flatgeobuf/3.0.1/test/data/UScounties.fgb"

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap", width = "700px", height = "700px")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      leafem:::addFgb(
        url = url, group = "counties",
        label = "NAME", popup = TRUE,
        fillColor = "blue", fillOpacity = 0.6,
        color = "black", weight = 1) %>%
      addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("counties")) %>%
      setView(lng = -105.644, lat = 51.618, zoom = 3)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

**Using `leafgl` (WebGL-Renderer):**

```
library(sf)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(leafgl)

plz <- st_read("C:/Users/user/Downloads/plz-gebiete.shp", layer = "plz-gebiete")

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap", width = "700px", height = "700px")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addGlPolygons(data = plz, color = ~plz, popup = "note", group = "plz") %>% 
      addLayersControl(overlayGroups = "plz")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Have you found a way to fill the polygons in the leafem-case? It does not seem to work for me, [see here](https://gist.github.com/DavZim/414e30fb09b2e1d06e22464b83249cc6). Note that the geometries are multipolygons and not linestrings.

Comment: I am just trying to convert the Shapefile to .fgb, but I have to update GDAL, since Flatgeobuf was introduced in 3.1 and I am still on 3.0.4. I'll update my answer as soon as I managed. Also note that `leafgl` works only with polygons and not multipolygons.

Comment: I had to do that yesterday... Version 3.1.2 (came out half-way through my installation attempts) worked best. To spare you the process, the file can be found [here](https://github.com/DavZim/misc/blob/master/local_map.fgb)

Comment: This is not the plz-gebiete Shapefile or? I am still getting the US counties with this file. Could you run `ogr2ogr -f FlatGeobuf plz.fgb plz-gebiete.shp` in the directory where the shapefile is and upload the resulting `plz.fgb`?

Comment: Sure, the file is too big for github, so I uploaded it to [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qw1k1ge9eyi98nd/plz.fgb?dl=0)

Comment: I didnt manage to install GDAL 3.1 until now. But here is a tweet where Flatgeobuf works with polygons and the fillColor seems to work: https://twitter.com/TimSalabim3/status/1264201631538831360

Answer (score 4):

## Approach 1: minimize polygons

As hinted in the comment by Grzegorz T., you can change the precision of the underlying polygon file. Reducing the file size increased load time by around **3x** on my computer.

The [Visvalingam and Douglas-Peucker algorithms](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.95.5882%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&psig=AOvVaw3L71xFcdxTnyuvlfHNSQEg&ust=1593970876982000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA0QjhxqFwoTCJiymrKStOoCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD) implemented in the [`rmapshaper`](https://github.com/ateucher/rmapshaper) package simplifies polygons by iterating over the points used to define the polyons and removing "extraneous points" while still "maintaining the shape".

```
library(rmapshaper)

# baseline object size
object.size(df)/1e6  # 61. MB

# simplyfy the spatial object
# `keep_shapes=T` ensures no polygons are dropped
df2 <- ms_simplify(df, keep_shapes = TRUE)
object.size(df2)/1e6 # 11.8 MB

# decreasing the percentage of points to keep from 5% (default) to 1% 
# doesn't result in significantly smaller object size, but still
# improves the loading speed
df3 <- ms_simplify(df, keep = 0.01, keep_shapes = TRUE)
object.size(df3)/1e6 # 9.8 MB
```

## Approach 2: render polygons as points

Points are much smaller than polygons. You might consider taking the centroid of each polygon and rendering those. This renders in about 1-2s on my machine, about a *50-100x* speedup.

```
library(tidyverse)
pts <- st_centroid(df) %>% 
  st_geometry() %>% 
  do.call(rbind, .) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  setNames(c("lng","lat"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(pts) %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(radius = 1)
  })
}
```

## Approach 3: render polygons as clustered points

Similar speed to approach 2, but potentially cleaner in presentation.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(pts) %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())
  })
}
```

Comment: These are some valuable approaches, esp. the first one. I was a bit intimidated by `rmapshaper` and its dependencies, but it seems it pays off. Ill wait a bit if someone has option for actually pre-rendering the map.